# Unresolved reference: findViewById

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, findviewbyid

I am currently taking the Google android developer course and was trying to work on the dice app but when calling the findViewById method it keeps giving me an error. I can't figure out why especially since I already called this method for the button.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        rollButton.setOnClickListener { rollDice() }
    }
}

    private fun rollDice() {
        val dice = Dice(6)
        val diceRoll = dice.roll()
        val diceImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)   //error comes up on this line
        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_2)
    }


    class Dice(private val numSides: Int) {
        fun roll(): Int {
            return (1..numSides).random()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `findViewById` is method of `Activity` ... so obviously you cannot use it in top level functions ... prolly it's just a typo and you should move bracket from before to after this function

Answer (score 1):

Put the function

```
  private fun rollDice() {
    val dice = Dice(6)
    val diceRoll = dice.roll()
    val diceImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)   //error comes up on this line
    diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_2)
  }
```

inside of MainActivity class.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this

```
private fun rollDice(mainActivity: MainActivity ) {
    val dice = Dice(6)
    val diceRoll = dice.roll()
    val diceImage = mainActivity.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
    diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_2)
    }
```

**OR**

just write the function inside the MainActivity Class

Answer (score -3):

Change this line of your code:

```
val diceImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
```

To this:

```
val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

Comment: Absolutely wrong answer nothing will change.